# Pygame window does not displays anything, when i exit the program, it displays my program for a split second and then closes

Tags: python, debugging, pygame

I have made a very simple Pygame program in which **mixer** is used. I want to create a screen with a background image and a button on it. The *button* displays *Pause*. But when i run the program, the pygame window(the output) displays a black screen. And when i type e which is for exit(as you can see in the code, in the mainloop, i've added specifications for letters which i can press to either- close(e), resume(r) or pause(p)), it flashes my program for a second(i am very sure the time it displays it for is lesser than a second) and then exits.
I also noticed, once i actually debugged it and it ran but the pygame window was non-responsive so i had to close and run again and to my vain, the screen was again blank.
**This is my code:**

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame import mixer
pygame.init()
mixer.init()

run = True

win = pygame.display.set_mode((690, 385))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Rhyme Library")
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREY = (30, 30, 30)
BGIMG = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Vinod/Desktop/Pygame Learn/musicpy.jpg')
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Corbel',35)
win.blit(BGIMG, (0,0))

                
def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic,ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Corbel',35)
    text = smallfont.render('Pause' , True , WHITE, ((x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2))))
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, ac, (x, y, w, h))  # creates a rect object 
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "pause":
                mixer.music.pause()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x, y, w, h))  # creates a rect object 
    #win.blit(text)
    #text1 = smallfont.render('Resume' , True , WHITE)
    #pygame.draw.rect(win, BLACK,(x, 160, 60, w))  # creates a rect object 
    #pygame.draw.rect(win, GREY, (x, y, w, 60))  # creates a rect object 
                    

                    

    #text2 = smallfont.render('Resume' , True , WHITE)
    #button2 = pygame.Rect(win, text2, (345, 220, 60, 1h))  # creates a rect object 



button("Pause", 345, 100, 150, 60, GREY ,BLACK, "pause")

    
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        run = False
        sys.exit()

                    

    #text2 = smallfont.render('Resume' , True , WHITE)
    #button2 = pygame.Rect(win, text2, (345, 220, 60, 150))  # creates a rect object 

#MAINLOOP                        
mixer.music.load("C:/Users/Vinod/Desktop/Pygame Learn/twinkle.mp3")
mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
mixer.music.play()
while True:
    print("Thanks for using the mixer created by Nishita Thakur.Kindly follow these guidlines.")
    print("Press 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume")
    print("Press 'e' to exit the program")
    query=input("")
    if query=='p':
        mixer.music.pause()
        
    elif query=='r':
        mixer.music.unpause()
        
    elif query=='e':
        mixer.music.stop()
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input Entered")
        
pygame.display.update()
```

I tried to find answers in Stackoverflow but no one had this issue so there was no such question. I want it to display my program and i have tried several times but i could not locate its bugs.  I'll be thankful to anyone who can help, as i am pretty new to pygame.
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You have to put the event loop in the main application loop

Comment: Do not use `input`. You have to get the pressed key by the keyboard events (`pygame.KEYDOWN`, `pygame.KEYUP` see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html))

Comment: Thanks Rabbid76, just a doubt please,should i add event loop in the While loop or the Mainloop?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the event loop in the main application loop. Do not use `input`. You have to get the pressed key by the keyboard events (`pygame.KEYDOWN`, `pygame.KEYUP` see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)):

```py
print("Thanks for using the mixer created by Nishita Thakur.Kindly follow these guidlines.")
print("Press 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume")
print("Press 'e' to exit the program")

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
        
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                mixer.music.pause()
        
            elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                mixer.music.unpause()
        
            elif event.key == pygame.K_e:
                mixer.music.stop()
                run = False
            else:
                print("Invalid Input Entered")

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```